# Use of binary search tree for line segment intersection

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I'm currently going through the "Line Segment Intersection" chapter from *Computational Geometry – Algorithms and Applications, 3rd Ed*. I'm not quite understanding how they're using the balanced binary search tree to describe the "status line" and as such I have a couple questions.

The first regards the key used for ordering the segments. I'm only familiar with using trees to order a simple list of numbers where the key is the number. But in this case the tree holds segments. I'm assuming the key is the start endpoint (point with smallest y value) of each segment. Is that right?

Second, when the event point (p) is either a segment endpoint or an intersection point, I need to be able to find the associated segments. But given the tree is keyed by the start endpoint of a segment, does that mean in order to find those other types of points of a segment my search will be linear?

Comment: I think you will need to refer to the definition of "status line" which the book (presumably) gives - it is not necessarily the raw data that is stored in the BST. Please include that definition in your question.

Comment: The book says - "In more detail, we store the segments intersecting the sweep line ordered in the leaves of a balanced binary search tree T. The left-to-right order of
the segments along the sweep line corresponds to the left-to-right order of the
leaves in T. We must also store information in the internal nodes to guide the
search down the tree to the leaves. At each internal node, we store the segment
from the rightmost leaf in its left subtree"

Comment: IIRC, there should be two trees: a tree containing events (segment starts, segment stops, segments intersect) keyed by position of the sweep line, and a tree containing line segments that intersect the sweep line (keyed by where they intersect the sweep line). The workflow is, pull the next event, if segment starts, insert it; if segment stops, delete it; if intersection, report and exchange the positions of the segments in the second tree. Every time we change the second tree, we may have to insert or delete intersection events from the first tree accordingly.

Comment: Thanks David. I think I know what I was missing. I understand all the high-level details of _what_ should happen at each event point, regarding the event queue and status structure, I just had an assumption that was throwing me off. Namely, I didn't realise I was assuming the status structure was fixed when the segments were added – when really the segments are used to calculate their specific intersection point given a location of the sweep line as input